# K modes calculating distance between each point and cluster centroid

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

I have a set of categorical variables to be clustered and so I am using k modes taken from a [github package](https://github.com/nicodv/kmodes). I want to get the distance of each observation (point) to the centroid of the cluster it belongs to.

This is what I have implemented so far:

```
kmodes_cao = kmodes.KModes(n_clusters=6, init='Cao', verbose=1)
kmodes_cao.fit_predict(data)

# Print cluster centroids of the trained model.
print('k-modes (Cao) centroids:')
print(kmodes_cao.cluster_centroids_)

# Print training statistics
print('Final training cost: {}'.format(kmodes_cao.cost_))
print('Training iterations: {}'.format(kmodes_cao.n_iter_))
```

I cannot use the Eucledean distance since the variables are categorical. What is the ideal way to calculate the distance of each point to its cluster centroid?

Comment: Look at the source code of the `KModes` function. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I looked through it but could not find how the distance being calculated. I am new in using data mining so could you please guide through?

Comment: It's even in the documentation, the `cat_dissim` parameter.

Comment: I am trying to apply it but couldn't figure out how to exactly use it. Can the code be posted here? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't use it, so no. You'll have to learn python yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Example if you have 2 variables V1 which can take A or B and V2 can take C or D
If your centroid is V1=A and V2=D

For each variable i, count when Vi != Ci(centroid i)

if you have an instance V1=A and V2=C then the distance from the centroid is 1
it is a binary distance 
hop that will help

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it is a little unclear. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Kmods count for each variable the mode value(the category the most represented). So at the end of your learning you get 6 centroids , 
assuming you have two variables in your dataset
C1 =(V1=category1, V2=category2)
...
...
C6 =(V1=categoryX, V2=categoryY)

if you want to predict the cluster for a new instance, you return the cluster that gives you the min distance
to count a distance between the instance and the cluster centroid C:
you can use this formula
distance=0
for each variable Vi
 if the value of Vi != Ci
  distance+=1
return distance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `matching_dissim()` from [kmodes](https://github.com/nicodv/kmodes) library.

To compare to rows in your dataset, one can be you centroid and other anyone. First you must install the library `Panda` then import the method  with this line:

```
from kmodes.util.dissim import matching_dissim
```

https://github.com/nicodv/kmodes/issues/39